# How to generate a xml-stylesheet declaration using RapidXML?

Tags: c++, xml, stylesheet, rapidxml

I know how to generate a regular xml header ()
but I don't see how to generate specifically a xml-stylesheet declaration.
Has anyone out there done it before?
Googling the question yielded nothing relevant.

Comment: xml-stylesheet elements are just an example of XML 'processing instructions'. RapidXML has a node_PI enum value for those elements.

However, as of version 1.13, the printing function that outputs a pi node is missing a call to 'print_attributes'
and therefore cannot output a valid processing instruction with attributes.

The author has been notified.

Comment: Workaround: print all the attributes' declarations, as you would expect them to be output, in the value string of the allocate_node function.